# Migrate existing data from Ali Cloud OSS to Amazon S3 Bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-datasync

I am wondering if there is any AWS service to migrate existing data from ali cloud OSS to Aws S3 bucket.
Here is a service in Ali Cloud which migrates from S3 to OSS. I need opposite
https://www.alibabacloud.com/blog/migrating-from-aws-s3-to-alibaba-cloud-oss-using-data-migration-service_594382

Answer (score 0):

No. Currently there is no such service.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Data Transfer Hub](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/implementations/data-transfer-hub/) solution, from the [AWS Solutions Library](https://aws.amazon.com/solutions/).

The solution supports data transfer to Amazon S3 from Alibaba Cloud OSS, Tencent COS, Qiniu Kodo, and Amazon S3 compatible cloud storage.